# Regex for specific word (starting with 1 letter and ending in numbers) after a positive lookbehind

Tags: regex, regex-lookarounds

Apologies if this is a basic question; I'm fairly new to regex and I have done a lot of googling, and I am still stuck on this expression.

I'm trying to capture a word, which starts with a letter and ends with digits. I am using a positive lookbehind since this word always occurs after a specific. However, there can sometimes be other words in between these 2, and I am inadvertently capturing those.

*Example of text:
Ref Text Word Z12345*

I want to capture **Z12345** only, which I know occurs after **Ref** always. However, I am capturing "Text" instead, using the text example above.

**(?<=Ref).(\w*)**

I've tried **(?<=Ref).(\w*)** and **(?<=Ref).(\w*(^aA-zZ))**

Answer (score 1):

You can't use a Positive Lookbehind, because it can't accept variable-length characters. Though one thing that may help you is matching without lookaround, enclose your actual match in a group and extract content of that group after pattern-match.

```
\bRef\b[\w\s]*?\b([a-zA-Z]\d+)\b
```

Your match, composed of a letter and digits, is contained in Group 1.

Check the demo [here](https://regex101.com/r/DQG3S5/1).

**Note**: Credits to @Thefourthbird for this regex refining.

Comment: I think you meant to put the lazy quantifier inside the first group - `(?:Ref[\w\s]+?)` instead of `(?:Ref[\w\s]+)+?` - otherwise you'd match all Ref...Z12345 groups together, if there are several of them in the text.

Comment: Definitely, thanks @oriberu

Comment: You don't need the first non capture group as in this scenario by itself it has no purpose. You might consider word boundaries for the "word" `\bRef\b[\w\s]*?\b([a-zA-Z]\d+)\b`

Comment: Way more precise than mine, I should remember using word boundaries when checking for words, thanks for sharing!